# How to get retrieve data from same column multiple times in same table in MySQL?

Tags: html, mysql

Currently i am facing issue in combining two different dates from one column of same table.
I want to use two different dates as START and END dates in my programming logic.

For example-

Dates

- 24/4/2014
- 25/4/2014
- 26/4/2014
- 27/4/2014
- 28/4/2014

Currently the logic code i am using is

```
    <html>
    <?php          
      $sql1="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE DATE LIKE '%$date1%' AND DATE LIKE        '%$date2%'";
    ?>
    </html>
```

With these i am getting an infinite series print with only 'date1' getting selected. Please help me in solving this issue.

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: we need to see some code to be able to help

Comment: Well, "two different dates from one column of same table" i guess your DB looks weird.. Why do you need that ?

Comment: this only returns one date because a field cannot have both date1 and date2 in it... is there an identifier in your table? Could you tell us what fields are available?

Comment: I want to select date as start and end date in order to obtain data (to and from the dates).

Comment: What is your `$date1` variable looks like?

Comment: Wribit, Can you suggest any other way to fulfill my purpose.

Comment: $date1 variable takes "date" as an input

Comment: I mean does your `$date1` variable have only DATE value like `28/4/2014` (OR) DATETIME like `28/4/2014 11:03:01`?

Answer (score 0):

Your DATE column can't match like both (the way your are trying). You can probably changed it to below using `OR` condition

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE `DATE` LIKE '%$date1%' OR `DATE` LIKE '%$date2%'
```

(OR) if your `$date1` variable hold only DATE part like `28/4/2014` then you can use `IN` operator like

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE `DATE` IN ('$date1','$date2')
```

(OR) if you want to select two different dates as START and END from same column probably get the `MAX(DATE)` and `MIN(DATE)` like

```
SELECT MAX(`DATE`) as END, MIN(`DATE`) as START  
FROM $tbl_name
```

Sidenote: `DATE` is a reserveword. So escape it using backtique